# mysql select fetch from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

```
TABLE USER 

USERID  NAMES  EMAIL
1       J      TES@ADM.COM1
2       K      TES@ADM.COM2
3       L      TES@ADM.COM3
4       M      TES@ADM.COM4

TABLE COMUNITY 

COMUNITY_ID  USERID  FAN_ID 
1            1       TES@ADM.COM3
2            4       TES@ADM.COM2
3            3       TES@ADM.COM4
4            2       TES@ADM.COM1
```

my userid is 1 - (name = j). how can i select these emails where my userid equal is 1 and these who have my userid (1) to their fan_id column
its like i want to get these emails i have where my userid and these who have mine

Comment: You should read up on the `INNER JOIN` construct in SQL - it provides exatcly what you are looking for. The `UNION` construct will help you add you the single row from the first part.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: It is not clear what you really want, for what I understand, do you want the email of the user with **ID 1** plus those emails of the fans of the user with **ID 1**?

Answer (score 1):

well is pretty simple :

```
SELECT
      c.fan_Id
FROM
      USERS u
      INNER JOIN COMUNITY c on u.USERID = c.USERID
WHERE 
      u.UserId = 1
```